Is it possible to make a socket emit from Laravel backend similar like it is possible in JavaScript
Hello i have question if its possible to make a socket emit from Laravel backend like it is possible from Javascript, without using any third parties programs.
This is my Javascript code that works
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.3.2/socket.io.js"></script>

const socket = io('https://socket.test.dev/');

 socket.emit('dataEntry');

This code works for emit and for listening to emits, now in backend i want to send emit when a process is finished, this is my code that i tried but does not work:
Http::post('https://socket.test.dev/', [
            'event' => 'finishedJob',
        ]);  

socket.on('finishedJob', () => {
    location.reload();
});

but no refresh happens i dont know if im missing something or if its possible to make socket emit from backend without using third parties apps.

Khm, you import third party script in your js code..

Instead of being any help you try to act smart, by third party script i meant avoiding using pusher or firebase that actually work in Laravel backend. Anyways thank you for reply.

Than make your question clear. You can check official docs here about broacasting (include local broadcasting with reverb): https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/broadcasting#reverb

My question is clear and again what you sent they use pusher as i said i dont want to use pusher all i have is the url of the socket, no keys no credentials. If you want to be of any help please provide a code where i send emit with a name to the socket and await it on JS. If its not possible say so.

Okey, clear answer on clear question - without keys and creditinals you cannot broadcast from php to js.
